# how to show agendaday with rowspan dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

i cant get any css that change the specific column header with title when event loader ....

[its mine.....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJkgz.png)

```
function initCalendar(myresources) {
$('#day-calendar').fullCalendar({
defaultView: 'agendaDay',
// defaultDate: '2017-12-28',
defaultDate: $scope.setDate,
aspectRatio: 1.8,
editable: true,
selectable: true,
eventLimit: true,
slotEventOverlap: true,
minTime: $scope.lessonStartTime,
maxTime: $scope.lessonEndTime,
contentHeight: 'auto',
slotLabelInterval: $scope.lessonTimeInterval,
slotLabelFormat: "HH:mm:A",
header: {
left: '',
center: 'Time',
right: ''
},
views: {
agendaDay: {
groupByDateAndResource: true,
}
},
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
resourceLabelText: "Venue",
allDaySlot: false,
resources: myresources,
events: eventsData,
eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
$(element).css('width', '200px');
},
```

[this what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fUMA.png)

i want with resource header and event width both are same
is it done by dynamicaly ?

help me ....

Comment: Is this the view you're using? https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.9.1/demos/vertical-resource-view.html . In that demo the events and the columns are almost the same width anyway. Is it such a big deal? It looks from your screenshot like you've already customised or themed the CSS, so perhaps that has something to do with your issue?

Comment: i'm looking to have the columns resize automatically, based on the width of the events.

Comment: Events don't have their own specific width, they just automatically become a little bit less wide than the column. The width of the column is in turn determined by the width of the calendar. Are you setting custom widths for your events somehow? Again, see that demo link I posted before. Find the calendar div in your browser tools and change its width temporarily. Watch how the columns and the events automatically resize themselves.